# onclick toggle between various text

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I want to toggle between multiple text when i click button.I have created a solution but i would to see a better solution and at end of last click event function i want it to continue to start from beginning.

```js
var qarray = ['canada', 'india', 'america']
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.style.background = 'green';
btn.style.fontSize = '25px';
btn.style.color = 'white';

btn.addEventListener('click', function quotes() {
  var textselect = document.querySelector('h2');

  var one = textselect.textContent = qarray[0];

  btn.addEventListener('click', function quoteone() {
    var two = textselect.textContent = qarray[1];
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var three = textselect.textContent = qarray[2];
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<h2>Shows 3 Country onclick</h2>

<button>Change</button>
```

Comment: You should almost never add an event listener inside another event listener. Every time you click on the button, you're cascading more listeners.

Comment: i learning javascript doing things like these even though it works i felt something is wrong with the code that is the reason why i posted here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a new event listener, you're not removing the old one. So eventually all the listeners run, and they keep adding more each time you click.

Just use a single event listener that uses a global variable to hold the current array index.

```js
var qarray = ['canada', 'india', 'america'];
var qindex = 0;
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.style.background = 'green';
btn.style.fontSize = '25px';
btn.style.color = 'white';

btn.addEventListener('click', function quotes() {
  var textselect = document.querySelector('h2');
  textselect.textContent = qarray[qindex];
  qindex = (qindex + 1) % qarray.length;
})
```

```html
<h2>Shows 3 Country onclick</h2>

<button>Change</button>
```

The modulus operator is used to make the index wrap around to `0` when you reach the end of the array.

Comment: its awesome @barmar

Answer (score 0):

```js
var qarray = ['canada', 'india', 'america']
     var btn = document.querySelector('button');
     btn.style.background = 'green';
     btn.style.fontSize = '25px';
     btn.style.color = 'white';
      var countClick =0;
   btn.addEventListener('click', function quotes() {
         var textselect = document.querySelector('h2');
    
         if(qarray.length > countClick) {
         textselect.textContent = qarray[countClick];
         countClick++;
         } else {
         countClick =0;
 

         textselect.textContent = qarray[countClick];
 
         }
      })
```

```html
<h2>Shows 3 Country onclick</h2>

<button>Change</button>
```